# how to auto cd into a directory when entering a bookmark in NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I would like nerdtree to auto cd vim into a directory after clicking on a bookmark, is there any easy way of doing this?

Thanks a lot :)

Jason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer is in NERDTree's help, you should have read it before asking: `:help nerdtree`

```
let NERDTreeChDirMode=2
```